# visual 2010 compatibility with cplex 12.2

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cplex

I tried integrating **visual 2010 and cplex 122**. It doesn't compile and throws error that error **LNK1112: module machine type 'x64'** conflicts with target machine type 'X86'. Also when i wrote a very small code it shows that it couldn't find "iostream.h" file. Anyhow i really appreciate any help...

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are on an x64 bit machine. Try going through the options and change the compilation options to x64. I think this kind of problem is solved in VS 2012.

Comment: I tried doing that earlier and it didn't work either.
Also i tried using another m/c with 32 bit, cplex 11.2 and visual c++ 2008. But here the error is 
C:\ILOG\CPLEX112\bin\x86_win32\cplex112.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.

Comment: Have you tried it in VS 2012? Just try it in the trial version.